# Struggling to create linspace (python)

Tags: python, numpy

Use numpy linspace to create an x-array for the interval `[−4.0, 4.0]` with
a spacing of exactly 0.01, endpoints included. Plot `sinh(x)` and `cosh(x)`. Calculate
the function values using whole array operations. Label the x-axis and the y-axis
(e.g. “sinh(x), cosh(x)”). Modify the x-limits to plot the functions without extra
space on the left hand and right hand side

Did this but output is not exactly 0.01

```
import numpy as np 
x=np.linspace(-4.0, 4.0, num=800, endpoint=True)
print(x)
```

Comment: I think you are off by one because of 0.0: `x=np.linspace(-4.0, 4.0, num=801, endpoint=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Practice with something smaller:

```
In [118]: np.linspace(-4,4,10)
Out[118]: 
array([-4.        , -3.11111111, -2.22222222, -1.33333333, -0.44444444,
        0.44444444,  1.33333333,  2.22222222,  3.11111111,  4.        ])
In [119]: np.linspace(-4,4,11)
Out[119]: array([-4. , -3.2, -2.4, -1.6, -0.8,  0. ,  0.8,  1.6,  2.4,  3.2,  4. ])
```

It's easy to forget that there will be 1 more eng points than gaps.